# D3 how to select element by ID when there is a dot in ID

Tags: javascript, select, d3.js

I have

```
<text id="element.id.with.dots" x="10" xml:space="preserve" y="10" stroke="none">
```

How can I select it using d3.select?
This doesn't seem to work, it returns null

```
var textElem = d3.select("text[id=element\\.id\\.with\\.dots]");
```

and this :

```
var textElem = d3.select("text[id=element.id.with.dots]");
```

gives me error in Firebug console window:

```
SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified
```

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a quoted string to delimit the value of your attribute:

```
var textElem = d3.select("text[id='element.id.with.dots']");
```

```js
var el = d3.select("text[id='element.id.with.dots']");
el.style({fill: 'red'})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg>
     <text id="element.id.with.dots" x="10" xml:space="preserve" y="10" stroke="none">Text/<text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to escape each period by putting a backslash `\` before it—then you can use `d3.select()` or `d3.selectAll()` as usual.

You can use `.replace(/\./g, '\\.')` to add the backslashes automatically.

Remember (thanks, [altocumulus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4235784/altocumulus)!), to escape the backslashes themselves with another backslash if you're editing the id manually.

> `d3.select("#element\\.id\\.with\\.dots")`

Comment: Don't forget to add double backslashes when passing the string into `d3.select()`. It's the same you are doing in your `.replace()`. https://jsfiddle.net/vL7360rn/2/. You want the backslash in the string and, therefore, need to escape it with the second backslash. If you miss out the second one, the single backslash will escape the following dot instead.

Comment: @altocumulus can't believe I forgot that—thanks. Answer has been edited accordingly.